# Firebase deploy failed even without changing the function from onCallable to onRequest

Tags: firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions

> Error: [functionName(us-central1)] Changing from a callable function to an HTTPS function is not allowed. Please delete your function and create a new one instead.

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Just remove the function from your source file, deploy the file, re-add the new function and re-deploy the source file. Right?

Comment: Deleting works but its annoying. I have to delete all functions every time I update anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Which version of Firebase CLI (`firebase --version`) are you using? Last night I updated `firebase-tools` package to 10.3.0 and functions deployment started giving me the error you mention. I downgraded to 10.2.2 and functions deployment started working as before.

Update:
Firebase team confirmed there is an issue with 10.3.0 firebase-tools. They are working on a fix:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4307

Comment: An update: they just released 10.3.1 with a fix. 
`npm i -g firebase-tools@latest` to update to the latest cli tools.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 01:

I think the main problem lies inside whether you are using a valid way to use .env file. Since I just recently have this kind of error. If you do use the .env file inside the structure of your folder, then

- You need to declare the path to .env file in all files which uses `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`. Example way is like this:
  `require("dotenv").config({path: "../.env"});`
- After that try to delete all existing Cloud Functions in Google Cloud Console
- Try deploy again: `firebase deploy --only functions`

I added a path to the .env file, since I checked Firebase Cloud Function Logs and it gave me error for all Cloud Functions which uses `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`. This .env file must be located inside the root project and placed inside folder `functions/`. Give it a try. Hope it works.

Solution no. 2:

You should check if there is a variable or function which doesn't give return value, like example below:

```js
const key = async () => {
  const response = await pk.accessSecret("PRIVATEKEY");
  return response;
};
```

I forgot to add a return value from the variable const key. Therefore I get so many errors like you do in all of my functions. And that errors cause firebase cli to state"

> Changing from a callable function to an HTTPS function is not allowed.
> Please delete your function and create a new one instead.

Comment: Hope it works for you. Please mark it as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I'm using process.env.K_SERVICE in my code. I get the same error when trying to deploy functions - "Changing from a callable function to an HTTPS function is not allowed. Please delete your function and create a new one instead.". If I delete the function and try to deploy, it works. This has started being the issue since I updated firebase cli package to latest.

For reference, K_SERVICE is an environment variable set by Google at runtime:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#runtime_environment_variables_set_automatically

Comment: As for Solution no.2, in Javascript you are allowed to have functions without return statement, so I don't see why would firebase cli be bothered.

Comment: @IvanJ - I think you are correct. I did upgrade to latest version of firebase cli last night. And yeah, the error still comes until now. I am gonna degrade to previous version. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me as well. `npm i -g firebase-tools@latest` did the trick.